# Jest tests not passing even though component seems to render correctly

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, leaflet, enzyme, react-leaflet

I am trying to learn to write unit tests for a react application I am building, but I keep running into problems when I try to do a shallow or full render. However when I look at in in chrome it doesn't throw errors and renders properly. I am trying to understand why the tests are failing.

**Failing Tests**

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';

//fails
it('Full render without crash', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});

//Passes
it('Shallow render without crash', () => {
  shallow(<App />);
});
```

The test that fails and gives the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property '_layerAdd' of null.
The above error occurred in the  component:

```
      in GeoJSON (created by Context.Consumer)

      in ForwardRef(Leaflet(GeoJSON)) (at Country.js:87)

      in ErrorBoundary (at Country.js:86)

      in div (at Country.js:85)

      in Country (at CountryList.js:21)

      in div (at CountryList.js:20)

      in CountryList (at MainMap.js:33)

      in div (created by Map)

      in Map (at MainMap.js:28)

      in MainMap (at App.js:9)

      in div (at App.js:8)

      in App (at App.test.js:9)
```

So I think it has to do with the way I am passing data from the CountryList component to the Country component.  But when I try to look at it during run time I cant find anything. I read data in from a json file in country list and feed it as props to the country component.

CountryList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Country from './Country.js';
import data from '../../../data/test.json';




export default class CountryList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }

    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Country data={data[0]} key={data[0].properties.NAME}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Country.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';
import SlidingPane from 'react-sliding-pane';
import "./SidePanel.css";



class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
          hasError: false,
          err : null, 
          help : null, 
        };
    }
  
    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
      // Display fallback UI
      this.setState({ 
          hasError: true,
          err : error,
          help : info
         });
      // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
      console.log("Error incoming");
      console.log(error);
      console.log(info);
    }
  
    render() {
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        // You can render any custom fallback UI
        console.log("There was an error");
        console.log(this.state.err);
        console.log(this.state.help);
      }
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }



export default class Country extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: 'green', 
            isPaneOpen: false
        }
        console.log("Props from contry list")
        console.log(props)
    }

    color_control = (color) => {
        return {color: this.state.color};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ErrorBoundary>
                    <GeoJSON 
                        data={this.props.data.geometry} 
                        key={this.props.data.properties.NAME}
                        style={this.color_control}
                    />
                </ErrorBoundary>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The other test that fails in the same place just with the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Any help would be appreciated. I am new with react and unit testing it so I may just be feeding the data into things incorrectly, but it appears to render correctly in browsers so I am stuck right now.

Comment: Mock third-party libs like Leaflet and React Leaflet. They add extra moving parts to your tests and cannot be expected to work correctly in Jest's fake DOM.

Comment: Is there a best practice for me to run unit tests on third-party libs then?

Comment: Yes. Mock them. Search for "jest libraryname" before attempting it yourself. See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6297#issuecomment-499809735 for leaflet.

Comment: Ok, I will try that, thanks for your help!